eliminar un registro mediante DELETE con un TRIGGER
espero que se encuentre bien, veran recien comienzo con el tema de los TRIGGERS debido a que quiero guardar los registros eliminados como parte de historial,
el detalle esta que al momento de hacer la ejecucion de la clausula DELETE
ya no me permite eliminar el registro, cabe decir el codigo funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora que le puse un TRIGGER a mi tabla ya no la elimina :,v .
mi codigo principal es este
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include("connect.php");
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    
    //ignorar esto 
    //$rescueData= "SELECT * FROM employes WHERE id_emp= '$id' ";
    //$rData= mysqli_query($conn, $rescueData);

    //codigo que elimina un registro
    $drop= "DELETE FROM employes WHERE id_emp = '$id' ";
    $send_drop = mysqli_query($conn, $drop);

    if($send_drop){
        header("location: index.php");
    }else{
        echo "Registro no eliminado";
        }

?>

El TRIGGER QUE CREE
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_employes 
AFTER DELETE ON employes 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO employes(id_emp, emp_name, emp_lastname) 
VALUES (OLD.id_emp, OLD.emp_name, OLD.emp_lastname) ; 
END;//

Y al momento de querer eliminar el registro me lanza el error
ncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Can't update table 'employed' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger in

Estoy investigando sobre el tema, pero al ser la primera vez, nose muy bien como van los tiros jaja. podrian ayudarme con alguna sugerencia? :v.

El trigger que publicas no se lanzará al borrar de la tabla employes, pues está creado sobre la tabla employed (una termina con S y la otra con D), por lo que no tiene nada que ver con el error que estás comentando, a menos que haya otro trigger asociado a la tabla employes que elimine sobre la tabla employed, con lo que si que se lanzaría.

gracias amigo fue un error de dedo editare nuevamente la pregunta gracias por la observacion.

El problema está en el nombre de las tablas porque en el trigger has cambiado los nombres de las tablas, y estás eliminando de la tabla employes y volviendo a crear en la misma tabla.
El trigger debería ser:
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_employes 
AFTER DELETE ON employes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO employed(id_emp, emp_name, emp_lastname) 
VALUES (OLD.id_emp, OLD.emp_name, OLD.emp_lastname) ; 
END;


gracias bro tenias razon. tu respuesta es valida.
